# save() saves all fields except ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model "Contest" with one m2m field called "teams" which is related to a model "Team".
I overrided the method save. In my *save()* function (the one that's overriding), I need a queryset (in my save overrinding function) with all the objects related to my *team* m2m field. The code is `self.teams.all()` but it won't work because my models is not yet registered in database right ? So I call `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` now my models is saved and I can get my queryset ?
I can't. The queryset is empty, even if I registered team(s). `<QuerySet []>`
Why does `super.save()` save immediately all the fields except the m2m ?
**I use exclusively the django admin web site to create models. No *manage.py shell* or form.**

My model :

```
class Contest(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, unique=True, default="InactiveContest", blank=True)  # Ex: PSGvMNC_09/2017
id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, verbose_name="opposants")
date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
winner = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name='gagnant', related_name='winner', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
loser = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name='perdant', related_name='loser', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
bet = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Nombre de paris', default=0, blank=True, null=0)
active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self._state.adding:
        self.active = False
        # Django's id field immitation
        last_id = Contest.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id')).get('id__max')
        if last_id is not None:
            self.id = last_id + 1
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
print(Contest.objects.get(id=self.id)) # Works --> model saved in db... in theory
    queryset = self.teams.all() # Empty all the time !
```

Once *save()* (the overrinding one) has been executed one time, the problem is solved and next times (modifications) I can get my queryset so I could just use `self._state.adding` but this method obliges me to save 2 times (creation, editing).
I need to understand why `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`behaves like this and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that implementation of `ManyToManyField` does not use the database table of the model. It uses third table for connection between two models.

Each model has its own database table. In your example

```
model Contest -> table app_contest
model Team   -> table app_team
```

However, `app_contest` does not have field `teams` in it. And `app_team` does not contain field `contest`.

Instead, there is a third table e.g. called `app_contest_team` that consists of three columns:

- id
- contest_id
- team_id

And stores pairs of `contest_id` + `team_id` that represent connection between contests and teams.

So `queryset = self.teams.all()` is equal to the SQL expression:

```
SELECT * FROM app_teams WHERE id in 
    (SELECT team_id from app_contest_teams WHERE contest_id = '{self.id}');
```

Thus, you can see that you cannot anyhow manipulate `ManyToManyField` without having an instance initially **saved** in database. Because only **after** inserting into table `app_contest` it receives unique ID which can be later used for creating entries in the third table `app_contest_teams`.

And also because of that - `save()` is not required when you add new object to `ManyToManyField` because table of the model is not affected

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Is it possible to automatically run a function at each save?

Comment: @Noah7. Yes. You can override `save()` as you did and make the call after `super` call